Loading an SQL dump is slow
note: I initially asked this question on stackoverflow, but was told superuser would be a better place for it.
I'm having performance issues while loading an sql dump into a new schema on my development machine: Creating the dump is quite fast (around 30s) but loading it back in takes more than 10 minutes.
My actual use case doesn't require an actual dump, I just need to clone one database (/schema ?), on the same server, as fast as possible. Doing a dump & load is simply the only way I've found to do that for now.
Here's what I'm doing so far:
mysqldump --opt MY_DATABASE > ~/my-db-dump.sql
mysql MY_NEW_DATABASE < ~/my-db-dump.sql

(I'll eventually combine these two steps, but this helps me see what part takes time, and allows inspecting the generated SQL)
The dump is 300MB, and contains the statements I would expect from the --opt flag:

UNIQUE_CHECKS=0
FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0
DISABLE KEYS

etc...
I've also tried increasing innodb_buffer_pool_size and disabling innodb_doublewrite, without success:
+-------------------------+-------------+
| Variable_name           | Value       |
+-------------------------+-------------+
| innodb_buffer_pool_size | 17179869184 |
| innodb_doublewrite      | OFF         |
+-------------------------+-------------+

I asked a colleague to try loading my dump on his computer, and that took 40 seconds so I am pretty sure the issue is not on the dump side. We have essentially the same values in sql VARIABLES, apart from version_compile_machine (x86_64 vs aarch64), and a few timestamps, process IDs and file paths.
What might explain the difference between the two ? Could it be only caused by the different devices ?

Edit: As requested in a comment, here are the results of a disk benchmark.
                        KDiskMark (3.1.4): https://github.com/JonMagon/KDiskMark
                    Flexible I/O Tester (fio-3.28): https://github.com/axboe/fio
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* MB/s = 1,000,000 bytes/s [SATA/600 = 600,000,000 bytes/s]
* KB = 1000 bytes, KiB = 1024 bytes

[Read]
Sequential   1 MiB (Q=  8, T= 1):  3567.022 MB/s [   3483.4 IOPS] <  2267.76 us>
Sequential   1 MiB (Q=  1, T= 1):  1117.216 MB/s [   1091.0 IOPS] <   917.91 us>
    Random   4 KiB (Q= 32, T= 1):   970.079 MB/s [ 242519.8 IOPS] <   131.70 us>
    Random   4 KiB (Q=  1, T= 1):    54.364 MB/s [  13591.2 IOPS] <    72.96 us>

[Write]
Sequential   1 MiB (Q=  8, T= 1):  3176.464 MB/s [   3102.0 IOPS] <  2256.61 us>
Sequential   1 MiB (Q=  1, T= 1):   746.099 MB/s [    728.6 IOPS] <  1115.53 us>
    Random   4 KiB (Q= 32, T= 1):   925.396 MB/s [ 231349.2 IOPS] <   136.67 us>
    Random   4 KiB (Q=  1, T= 1):    72.096 MB/s [  18024.0 IOPS] <    52.80 us>

Profile: Default
   Test: 1 GiB (x5) [Measure: 5 sec / Interval: 5 sec]
   Date: 2024-11-18 10:29:32
     OS: ubuntu 22.04 [linux 6.8.0-48-generic]

I've also tried copying the entire /var/lib/mysql (with 4 other similarly sized databases). Using cp, that took less than 5 seconds (I suspect there's some weird optimisation going on there). Using the file explorer, it took 33s.


model: Dell XPS 15
cpu: 13th Gen intel i7
RAM: 32 GiB
Storage: 1T nvme ssd


This question is now also on dba.stackexchange
